# CDI: Inject different bean in an EJB depending on the caller

Tags: jsf, ejb, cdi

I'm trying to inject a bean in a stateless EJB. But i would like that bean be different when EJB is called from a ManagedBean or from a EJB Timer.

Here is my EJB in which i inject a User bean:

**MyEjb.java**

```
@Stateless
class MyEjb{
    @Inject
    @CurrentContext
    private User user;

    public void foo(){
        System.out.println(user);
    }
}
```

Here is a EJB Timer that use the EJB:

**TimerTest.java**

```
@Singleton
@Startup
class TimerTest {

    @EJB
    private MyEjb myEjb;

    @Timeout
    public void doIt(Timer timer) {
        myEjb.foo();
    }   


    @Produces
    @CurrentContext
    public User produceCurrentUserInEjbTimer(){
        return new User("system");
    }
}
```

Finally, the ManagedBean using MyEjb :

**MyManagedBean.java**

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
class MyManagedBean {
    @EJB
    private MyEjb myEjb;


    public void bar() {
        myEjb.foo();
    }


    @Produces
    @CurrentContext
    @RequestScoped
    public User produceCurrentUserInManagedBean(){
        return new User(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser());
    }
}
```

When the timeout is reach, i would like that foo method of MyEbj use the system User created by the method produceCurrentUserInEjbTimer.

And when the bar method of the ManagedBean is invoked, i would like that foo method of MyEbj use the remote User of the FaceContext (created by the method produceCurrentUserInManagedBean).

Comment: And calling `MyEjb#foo` with the user as a parameter is not an option?

Comment: No, in fact, i also use the user in a Interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather have only one producer that checks if FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() != null then call the apropriate code:

```
public User produceCurrentUser(){
        if(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance() != null){
            return new User(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser());
        }
        else{
             return new User("system");
       }
    }
```

You can also inject you User directly on the timer or the ManagedBean and then use InjectionPoint object to know to which class your User is injected:

```
public User produceCurrentUser(InjectionPoint injectionPoint){
      System.out.println(injectionPoint.getBean());
}
```

You should also use @Named and @javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped as you have CDI on your application instead of @ManagedBean.

**UPDATE**

I'm not sure that there is a direct method to get the context of the injection, it wil be possible throw CDI extension but I've never try it.

What about obtaining a contextual instance by programmatic lookup:

```
    @Stateless
class MyEjb{
    @Inject @Any Instance<User> userSource;

    public void foo(String context) // you should define contexts your self as jms, jsf ...
    {
// Every expected context will have a qualifier
      Annotation qualifier = context.equals("jsf") ?
      new JSFQualifier() : new JMSQualifier();
      User p = userSource.select(qualifier).get();
      System.out.println(user);
    }
}
```

This was you can inject your EJB and pass the context param to foo:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
class MyManagedBean {
    @EJB
    private MyEjb myEjb;


    public void bar() {
        myEjb.foo("jsf");
    }
}
```

Comment: well, it's a solution! But i would have wished to let the container choose the right producer depending on the context (JSF, Timer, JMS, JAXRS, ...), no way ?

Comment: I've updated the post with an other option, I hope it'll help you.

Comment: That´s the same as passing the user object as parameter... It will not work with a interceptor.

Comment: What's the use case you forsee with interceptors

Comment: I will log all user action on method named saveXXX or updateXXX to save user id on the bean